# Draw line from one text element to another with css

Tags: html, css

I do have a list with text elements and I need to somehow draw a dashed line between element 1-1 and element 2-1.

At the end it should like more or less like this:

```
El 1-1     ----------------------|
El 1-2                           |
El 1-3                           |
El 1-4                           |
        El 2-1    ---------------|
        El 2-2
        El 2-3
```

I have no idea how to achieve this. I saw solutions on the web where people are drawing lines from div to another, ok. But this text (El 1-1 and El 2-1) can be anything, wider or smaller, and the horizontal lines have to adjust.

Currently I am playing around with table-cells and borders, but ... no real success.
Do you guys have any idea how this could be solved or at least for what I should watch out?
This is what I was trying so far:

```css
#div1 {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0 20px;  
}

#div1-1 {
  border-right: dashed 1px #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px
    display: table;
}
#div1-2 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  display: table;
}

#div1-1 p,
#div1-2 p {
  display: table-row;
}

#div1-1 p span,
#div1-2 p span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span.horizontal_dotted_line {
  display: table-cell;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000000;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  
  <div id="div1-1">
    <p><span>Cell 1-1-1 </span> <span class="horizontal_dotted_line"></span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-1-2</span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-1-3</span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-1-4</span></p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="div1-2">
    <p><span>Cell 1-2-1 </span> <span class="horizontal_dotted_line"></span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-2-2</span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-2-3</span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-2-4</span></p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: A pure-CSS solution for this is pretty unforgiving, challenged by viewport widths, text length etc.. Do you *have* to use CSS only? jQuery or similar can help a lot positioning divs at some corner of another and the like.

Comment: jQuery would be an option as well, if this helps, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible CSS only solution. I removed all the `table` display settings and used `flex` on the `p` elements which contain the spans. Also, I used relative positions on some of the elements in order to be able to move them vertically in order to achieve vertically centered alignment between text and lines:

```css
#div1 {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#div1-1 {
  border-right: dashed 1px #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#div1-2 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

#div1-1 p,
#div1-2 p {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.6em;
}

#div1-1 p span,
#div1-2 p span{
  padding-right: 10px;
}

span.horizontal_dotted_line {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000000;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5em;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">

  <div id="div1-1">
    <p><span>Cell 1-1-1 </span> <span class="horizontal_dotted_line"></span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-1-2</span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-1-3</span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-1-4</span></p>
  </div>

  <div id="div1-2">
    <p><span>Cell 1-2-1 </span> <span class="horizontal_dotted_line"></span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-2-2</span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-2-3</span></p>
    <p><span>Cell 1-2-4</span></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox!! I am sometimes that oldschool... omg!! That looks great and it's really flexible, no matter how long the text is. Perfect solution, @Johannes, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery

1. Get offset position of div1 and div 2

   div1.offset().top;

   div1.offset().left;
2. Use SVG polyline to draw dash line

```html
<svg>
    <polyline id="polyline" stroke-dasharray="10"></polyline>
</svg>
```

3. Set co-ordinates of line by getting offset position of div 1 and div 2

It will be responsive and having good control on lines.

Comment: @Martin is right, I only get a syntax error. And I don't see from your description how to draw the line (how to add coordinates or whatever is needed for this)

Comment: @JonSnow I found the answerer had put SVG HTML in the "JS" part..., but they've not yet actually added any JS for us to see

Comment: @TheCoder Aside from the fact that your code is not working, I don't see how to draw the horizontal line, then the vertical downwards and horizontal again (see scribble). I can only imagine that your code might draw a direct line (if at all)

Comment: @JonSnow you can add polyline attribute like this,
        polyline.attr("points", 100 ","  100 " " 400 "," 100 " " 400 "," 500 " " 500 "," 100);